# How to keep checkbox and label in one line in Laravel + Bootstrap form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-blade

My view has a form. In this form I have this:

```
<div class="row">
    {!! Form::label('math', 'Mathematics',
                     array('class' => 'col-xs-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-xs-5 text-right')) !!}
    {!! Form::checkbox('exams[1]', '2')!!}
</div>
```

Now it's looks like this:

[image]

How to keep label and checkbox in one line?

**Edit**

Solved like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-xs-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-xs-5 text-right">Mathematics
       {!! Form::checkbox('exams[1]', '2')!!}
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use CSS style `margin`

Comment: Is it possible with bootstrap, without manual css classes?

Comment: Nope. You can't rely on bootstap on this. You need to add custom css.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not recommend `checkbox` is not wrapping with label. For user friendly pov, you should wrap `checkbox` with `label`. Meaning, user no need click exactly on checkox position. It can also click on label as well. e.g `<label><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxWarning" value="option1">Your Label</label>`

Comment: Yes I just did the same

Answer (score 1):

Give a class or id to your field for example `checkbox`

```
{!! Form::checkbox('exams[1]', '2', false, ['class' => 'checkbox']) !!}
```

Now in your stylesheet code like this:

```
.checkbox {
   margin-top: 5px; // try +/- the pixel, check what works for you
}
```

Comment: Third argument in checkbox: `['class' => 'checkbox']` give me checked field. I think it's not possible, to give class to checkbox with Laravel

Answer (score 0):

give class or style to your checkbox

```
{!! Form::checkbox('exams[1]', '2', ['class' => 'asad'])!!}
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')' `

Comment: Yes, this is not correct. `'class'=>'asad'` should be array

Comment: @AlexLukinov fixed now

Comment: Same comment as for @Mahfuzul Alam answer

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code it's on the same line already, so you might wanna check if bootstrap is loaded.

as alternative you could add a class, like "mt10"

```
 {!! Form::label('math', 'Mathematics',
                 array('class' => 'col-xs-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-xs-5 text-right')) !!}
 {!! Form::checkbox('exams[1]', '2', null, array('class' => 'mt10'))!!}
```

And add some margin to the class (might be more or less pixels)

```
.mt10 { margin-top: 10px; }
```